# Random 1 or 2 in Foreach, each number has to be chosen equally many times

Tags: php, random

I'm creating a fairly simple tournament system where I have a couple of different teams in a mysql table. Each team will be distributed to either Group 1 or Group 2.

I know how to randomly distribute the teams, the problem is that they have to be evenly distributed in the groups.

What's the easiest way for me to deal with this?

Answer (score 4):

Create a list with the appropriate number of 1's and 2's. Then [`shuffle`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the list. Each team gets the number that winds up in its position in the list.

You know exactly how many 1's and 2's you'll get, since shuffling doesn't change the numbers, it just changes their order.

Comment: Ahh! Didn't know shuffle existed. Sounds like the right way to go!